# Swipe gesture menu

Tags: css, mobile, touch, swipe, gesture

I am trying to make this specific menu from the image.

[image]

As you can see from the photo, the menu is based on filtering and submitting the custom filter. The way this menu is aimed to be used is by swiping left or right depending on the user's choice as shown in this image.

[image]

When swiped, depending on which element is currently located in the trigger point, in this case, the center of the page, it would give it a custom class as shown here.

[image]

I understand that question is too broad to be fully answered and I totally agree with that. My aim is to get some sort of help or advice in which direction should I go in order to accomplish this (using a library you know or tutorial explaining similar issues).
** Also if someone has an idea of how to make these elements swipeable, it would be of great help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Provide some code(what you have done so far) so that we can help

Comment: So, until now I have only tried to make it with GSAP draggable plugin, but it didn't provide any help. Basically I am stuck at the beginning

Comment: In short you need to swipe the menu with mouse or drag the menu to next with mouse?

Comment: It's only for mobile users. It is supposed to be moved with finger drag

Comment: Ok and on desktop with mouse right?

Comment: The app is only going to be used on phone, so no desktop at all

Comment: Then you should change you tags so that the mobile app developer;s help you in that case

Comment: Totally agree, thanks for advice

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: Mention not! and @Luka sorry for long QA as i though its for web that's why i need some details

Comment: @Awais not a single problem and it is for web, just for mobile sized devices

Comment: Well in that i case i prefer to use `Carousel` here is the link of `OwlCarousel` [The link](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/) which works both for web and mobile

Comment: @Awais You have been of much help! I appreciate that :) I owe you a beer

Comment: Many Thanks @Luka. Hope that solve your problem Cheers! Do let me know if it help you so that i post that as an answer for others as well